# How do you change the Emacs init file to customize the font for new frames?

Tags: emacs, text-editor, customization, font-size, emacs-speedbar

I want to know, what text do I have to input in the .emacs file so that it uses a especific font (like the clean 5x8) on the new frames, such as with the speedbar. I can modify the speedbar font size and type by using SHIFT-LeftClick but I want it to stay by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of you guys, each one of the answers helped me in some way. Having just used emacs for a couple of months, it's proving to be really helpfull. With the exception of code completion like in most IDEs, emacs has a lot of features that I could never figure out without swimming thru the web.

Best regards and hope to continue to make a good use of SO!

Comment: Aha, another one turned to the One True Editor.  Have a look at the EMACS Wiki for more fun (like code completion modes): http://www.emacswiki.org/

Comment: Thnx :)
I've been wandering thru the Wiki for a while, but it's quite a lot of info to catch in just a few sessions overseas while making a simple Pong clone in C++ with OpenGL and SDL. I still have to get the main terms right (even more difficult, being that my native language is not english). But...i think that i'll get the hang of it eventually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several choices.  Perhaps the easiest is to use Customize to change the default frame font.  Choose Customize from the menu, use a regex to find default-frame-alist.

Set the Font property (You may have to add it to the list.)  Mine is set as

```
"-*-*-medium-r-normal--16-*-*-*-*-*-fontset-osaka"
```

Second choice is to actually set the default-frame-alist in your .emacs.

Here's a hint: set up your current frame the way you like it, then type

```
(pp (current-frame-configuration))^J
```

in the `*scratch*` buffer to find out all the frame parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Customize option `default-frame-alist`. End of story.

For font changes, see this page: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts.

Answer (score 0):

If you work in non-Debian linux, another way to set up a default font for emacs is to add emacs customisation to the file ~/.Xdefaults (in Debian, any file in `/etc/X11/Xresources/` is used; for example, `/etc/X11/Xresources/emacs`):

```
emacs*font: 7x14
```

which may be followed by different other options:

```
emacs*Background: DarkSlateGray
emacs*Foreground: Wheat
emacs*pointerColor: Orchid
emacs*cursorColor: Orchid
emacs*bitmapIcon: on
emacs.geometry: 100x40
```

The name of the font above is not explicit, in some situations you may need to specify it explicitly, such as

```
emacs.font -*-*-medium-r-normal--14-130-75-75-c-70-fontset-startup
```

The exact name of your preferred font can obtain, as in the above answer, by typing

```
(pp (current-frame-configuration))^J
```

in the `*scratch*` buffer. You would need to reload X.

Comment: No need to reload X. Make changes to `~/.Xdefaults`, as suggested above. Close emacs. Run the command: `xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults`. Restart emacs.

Answer (score 0):

```
(eval-after-load 'speedbar
  (add-to-list 'speedbar-frame-parameters '(font . "5x8")))
```

or

```
M-x customize-variable
speedbar-frame-parameters
```

Comment: Here is GNU Emacs 22.3.1. There is no variable `speedbar-frame-alist`

Comment: Sorry, should be <code>'speedbar-frame-parameters</code>.  I am running Emacs-23 pretest; not sure if it's in Emacs-22.3.